# Wordpress: существует ли плагин для записи макроса и его выполнения горячими клавишами?

Tags: wordpress

Для конкретизации вопроса, поставлю конкретную задачу. Есть ли в Wordpress плагин, который позволяет:

- Записать в макрос действия, выполненные во встроенном или добавленном через другой плагин текстовом редакторе (статей), например, выделения текста конкретным цветом.
- Назначить горячие клавиши для выполнения макроса.

Answer (score 0):

Для выполнения автоматизированных действий в браузере нужно использовать браузерное/десктопное ПО. Напр iMacros (есть аддоны к браузерам).

А в ВП (и вообще в сайтостроительсве) для "выделения текста конкретным цветом" нужно использовать стили (css).

Comment: Wordpress представляет собой интерес в том числе и потому, что в нём есть WYSIWYG-редактор статей. Главное - чтобы можно было выделять текст цветом так же просто, как в ворде, где есть возможность записать макрос и назначить горячие клавиши, в том числе и выделение конкретным цветом. А как выделение цветом  в Wordpress реализовано - через HTML-атрибуты, CSS-стили или ещё каким-то способом - это для рассматриваемой задачи не важно.

Comment: Рассматривайте браузер как аналог ворда, а всё, что в нём (не важно ВП или что-то ещё) - как документ. Макросы исполняются в браузере (ворде), а не в документе. Применяются к документу.

Comment: И да. Если понадобилось что-то так автоматизировать - верный признак неправильного подхода к решению задачи.

Comment: Я бы не стал делать таких громких заявлений :) Хорошо, можете привести пример из веб-разработки, в котором автоматизация является неверным путём к решению задачи, а есть более рациональный?

Comment: Автоматизация мышиной возни? Нет я не могу привести таких примеров за отсутствием таковых в принципе. Так не решаются задачи. Хотите узнать что и как делать правильно - опишите задачу какую хотите решить в отдельном вопросе. Задача - это не "как автоматизировать мышу" (на это я уже ответил), а "как произвести.. ну например замену цвета (чего именно?) во всех постах".

Comment: Допустим, на каком-либо сайте часто используется [контекстное выделение цветом](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-colors). Реализовано это как раз через css-классы, но не сведущих в веб-технологиях WYSISYG-ориентированных менеджеров это не должно волновать. Выделять цветом каждый раз через меню - не айс, так же как копировать и вставлять через контекстное меню, открываемое ПКМ. Тут и подойдут правильно подобранные сочетания клавиш (например, alt+m для `text-muted`, alt+p для `text-primary` и так далее). Какие альтернативные решения Вы можете предложить?

Comment: Это другой вопрос - задавайте его отдельно