# Можно узнать только что отработавший JavaScript-код с помощью инструментов Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Можно ли с помощью инструментов браузера Chrome узнать только тот код JavaScript, который только что отработал?

Расскажу, как я пришел к этому вопросу. Другой мой вопрос, [Wordpress: существует ли плагин для записи макроса и его выполнения горячими клавишами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634370/wordpress-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0/634446#comment895224_634446), так и остался без ответа, а вопрос [Launch recorded macros by custom hotkeys in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42668761/launch-recorded-macros-by-custom-hotkeys-in-wordpress) (Можно ли запустить записанный макрос пользовательским сочетаниями клавиш?) таки вообще сразу минус получил. Поковырявшись с плагином iMacros для Chrome и поняв, что возможности назначать сочетания клавиш там нет (а зачем вообще тогда нужен этот плагин...) , я понял, для решения поставленных задач придётся писать плагин для Wordpress.

Как программно назначать сочетания клавиш в JavaScript, я уже [нашел](https://myrusakov.ru/javascript-hotkey.html), осталось понять, по какому принципу редактор статей Wordpress включает режим жирного шрифта или выделения цветом в режиме WYSIWYG и по этому же принципу сделать свои собственные макро-команды. Мне нужно знать именно тот кусок кода, который выполняется при нажатии клавиши "жирный шрифт" или "цвет шрифта", но без условно, ответ на текущий вопрос понадобится и в других задачахю

Comment: developer tools ->  network показывает что выполняется. можно вытащить данные оттуда

Comment: Network - это отслеживание запросов к серверу, так? Но ведь большая часть JS-кода (не включая технологию AJAX) выполняется на клиентской стороне...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: GoogleCrome]Есть отслеживание в хроме. Можно даже точку останова поставить. Вот на фото есть точка останова которая сработала при срабатывании скрипта.Я думаю тут коменты излишни в плане где искать это окно. Но если кто то еще не знает то правая кнопка мыши -> Просмотреть код -> Закладка Sourses и ищите свой скрипт. И там уже воюйте с ним.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! А где именно это отслеживание?

Comment: Сейчас домой приду скину более точно

Comment: Заранее благодарю Вас за уделённое вопросу внимание.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите решение проблемы более детально, чтобы пользователям было легче понять ваш ответ. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/148901)

Comment: :) Все можете пробовать

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! В принципе всё понял и попробовал, но всё же не всегда удаётся перехватить конкретную отработку кода, например, добавление markdown для выделения жирным. Пока не придумал, как сформулировать вопрос.